# Rails | Cucumber | acl9 | AccessDenied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, acl9

I am ramping up Cucumber, and I am having a issue getting one of my first tests to pass.  The exception I am getting is:

```
And I visit the new contract screen
  Acl9::AccessDenied (Acl9::AccessDenied)
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
  (eval):2:in `visit'
  ./features/step_definitions/manage_contracts_steps.rb:2:in `/^I visit the (.*) screen$/'
  features/manage_contracts.feature:15:in `And I visit the new contract screen'
```

Here is my cucumber feature ...

```
Background:
Given the following user records
| login  | password | name | role         |
| bob    | secret   | Bob  | 'PSCM Staff' |
| admin  | secret   | Frank| admin        |

@new
Scenario: Create Contract
When I log in as "bob" with password "secret"
And I visit the new contract screen
Then I should see "Contract Name"
```

My steps.rb:

```
Given /^the following user records$/ do |table|
   table.hashes.each do |hash|
     role = hash.delete('role')
     u = Factory(:user, hash)
     u.has_role!(role) if role
   end
end

When /^I visit the (.*) screen$/ do |screen|
  visit path_to(screen)
end
```

Finally in my controller.rb I have the following access_control block:

```
  before_filter :load_contract, :except => [:cancel_action,:new,:create]

  access_control do
    allow :admin
    allow logged_in, :to => [:index,:show,:log]
    allow "PSCM Staff", :to => [:new,:create]
    allow :editor, :of => :contract
  end
```

The senario works fine when I follow the steps explicitly from the browser.

Sorry for the long post, and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue.  In case this helps some one else.  The issue was including quotes with in the pipes in this line

`| bob    | secret   | Bob  | 'PSCM Staff' |`

it should read

`| bob    | secret   | Bob  | PSCM Staff |`